# Wordpress Blog Older post & Newer posts not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

In my blog older post and newer post link not working properly

When user press on the link it Just reloads to the same page itself
the URL creates is http://www.website.com/blog/page/2/

I believe the correct URL should be http://www.website.com/blog/2014/05/page/2/

This is my code in loop.php

```
<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( ' Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            </div><!-- #nav-below -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using " new WP_Query(); " in loop.php ?
If yes then post your  WP_Query(); PHP code with out HTML(If required).

Comment: No, am not using "new wp_quer();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what are you doing in starting with loop.php

This code could be helpful.

```
<?php
//The Query
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( 'showposts=10&cat='.$category_id.'&paged='.$paged );

//The Loop
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

// display posts as you need

endwhile;

// pager Method -1
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( ' Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
        </div><!-- #nav-below -->
```

//Or you can use Paged Method -2

```
// pager
if($wp_query->max_num_pages>1){?>
    <p class="pager">
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<=$wp_query->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category_id).'page/'.$i;?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="active"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>
        <?php
    }
    if($paged!=$wp_query->max_num_pages){?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category_id).'page/'.$i;?>">Category</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```